# NodeJS nested lambda callback unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js, lambda

I cannot figure out why in my nested callbacks I can't get my `sendKey` function to run. I tried `this.sendKey`, `sendkey.sendKey`, but neither way worked.

Instead `isAlive` function is getting called.

```
var sendkey = this.sendKey;

this.on = function (callbackOn) {
    this.isAlive(function (status) {
        if(status){
            //this.sendKey('KEY_POWER');
            sendkey.sendKey('KEY_POWER');
        }       
        callbackOn("");
    });
};

this.sendKey = function(key, callback) {
    //this code never fires
};
```

Comment: converting it all to old style aka function(args){...} did not help to solve problem

Comment: You are misunderstanding the keyword `this` in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. It's all about execution context.